# Render image transforms on the staging server

Tags: image-transforms, s3

Are normal workflow involves developing the site locally but making all the database level changes (fields and data) on the sever.

The trick has always been assets.  We don't bother syncing assets, just the database which works fine except when it comes to newly defined image transforms.  They need to be run on the server first to work properly locally.

We end up using Amazon s3 mostly to get around this exact issue but it would be better if I could somehow set a config setting that would tell all my image transforms to use the staging domain.  Is that possible somehow?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is. Do you want the images to be on one server, but the transforms on another?